# How to access IFrame elements from a WebBrowser

Tags: c#, iframe, browser, recaptcha

I have a WebBrowser control that has an iFrame without an ID. That iFrame changes itself each time it's navigated. So I need to access the iFrame elements that have the values appearing on my WebBrowser. The iFrame is loaded from Google Recaptcha API. Here is how the iFrame looks like:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="300" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=aKeyIsWrittenHere" width="500"></iframe>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do with HtmlAgilityPack, and if not, then how to do it. I have noticed that the frame count for the WebBrowser window is always 0

```
webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames.Count //returns 0 (I am checking it in DocumentCompleted)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks SOF.

Comment: Try checking it some time after DocumentCompleted.

Comment: @deadlock did you find a solution?